Why do the positions of my elements move?
I am having problems with my header. When I open inspect element, everything looks correct and how I intended.

However, when its not open, my header looks like this

Here is my HTML


<nav>
  <div><img src="./Digital Assets/Capture.PNG" style="height: 20vh; width: 100%;"></div>

  <div class="Nav" style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: -40px;">
    <ul>
      <h2 style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Home</a></h2>
      <h2 style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">About Us</a></h2>
      <h2 style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Tours</a></h2>
      <h2 style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Bookings</a></h2>
      <h2 style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Contact Us</a></h2>
      <img src="./Digital Assets/Logo2.PNG" style="position: relative; top: -150px;">
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



Why is this happening?
Tried to create a header with the logo in the center and the navigation underneath being central but it disappears off-screen when the page is fullscreen.

top: -40px; sounds suspiciously like the culprit

Not sure if this is the reason for your problem here, but you should really fix your faulty HTML. ul is not allowed to have h2 or img elements as children. Lists need to contain list items, li.

I would approach this layout differently. For instance, consider using the background image as a background-image property instead of an img tag, since its role is primarily aesthetic and not crucial for screen readers. This way, you can avoid using relative positions and unnecessary top and left properties.
Here's an example (replace the first div's height with your desired value):
    <div style="background-image:url('./Digital Assets/Capture.PNG'); height:15em; display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;">
    <div style="flex-grow:1;display: flex; align-items: center;"><img src="./Digital Assets/Logo2.PNG" style="height:5em;"></div>
        <nav class="Nav">
            <ul>
                <li style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Home</a></li>
                <li style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">About Us</a></li>
                <li style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Tours</a></li>
                <li style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Bookings</a></li>
                <li style="display: inline-block; margin-inline: 3em;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: antiquewhite;">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>

Also as someone else commented the h2 elements should be li elements.
